# R sample a raster with square polygons

Tags: r, polygon, raster, sampling, spatstat

I would like to sample a big raster by creating In small raster 100x100 cells.
I don't know how to do that so any ideas are welcome

My actual lead :

```
library(raster)
library(spatstat)
library(polyCub)

r <- raster(ncol=1000,nrow=1000) # create empty raster
r[] <- 1:(1000*1000)             # Raster for testing
e <- extent(r)                   # get extend
# coerce to a SpatialPolygons object
p <- as(e, 'SpatialPolygons')  


nc <- as.owin.SpatialPolygons(p) #polyCub
pts <- rpoint(50, win = nc)
plot(pts)
```

Now I need to generate 100x100 cell square around my 50 points and I would like to crop `r` using those square and stack each small raster individually ...

Comment: Your objective is unclear to me: Are the given inputs a big raster in the format of the `raster` package and some (50) given points in the `ppp` format of `spatstat` and then you want to extract 100x100 raster cells around each point? What do you mean by stacking each small raster individually?

Comment: Also there must be edge cases to think of: E.g. what should happen when a point is close to the raster border and the raster doesn't contain a 100x100 grid around it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, _i)_ You had understood exactly what I'm looking for! extract a 100x100 raster cell around each point. For me the best output will be a raster stack. _ii)_ I don't know (yet) own to manage point near the raster border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @adrian-baddeley basically has the ingredients to do what
you want. If you simply want a list of small `im` objects that contain
the 100x100 box you simply subset `im` objects by `owin` objects to
extract the relevant region. Here is an example (with fewer points to
avoid overplotting)

```r
library(raster)
library(spatstat)
library(maptools)

r <- raster(ncol=1000,nrow=1000) # create empty raster
r[] <- 1:(1000*1000)             # Raster for testing
e <- extent(r)                   # get extend
# coerce to a SpatialPolygons object
p <- as(e, 'SpatialPolygons')  

nc <- as.owin.SpatialPolygons(p)
set.seed(42)
pts <- rpoint(7, win = nc)

rim <- as.im.RasterLayer(r)
Box <- owin(c(-50,50) * rim$xstep, c(-50,50) * rim$ystep)
```

The following is a list of `im` objects of size 100x100

```r
imlist <- solapply(seq_len(npoints(pts)),
                   function(i) rim[shift(Box, pts[i])])
```

Here is a plot of the `im` objects in the region and the points on top

```r
plot(pts)
for(i in imlist) plot(i, add = TRUE)
plot(pts, pch = 19, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

You can convert to a list of raster layers with

```r
rasterList <- lapply(imlist, as, Class = "RasterLayer")
```

PS: The following is a list of `im` objects of the original size with
`NA` outside the 100x100 box if you need that format instead

```r
imlist <- solapply(seq_len(npoints(pts)),
                   function(i) rim[shift(Box, pts[i]), drop = FALSE])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `spatstat` then you need to convert the raster object `r` into an object of class `im` supported by `spatstat`. You can do this conversion in the `maptools` package. Call this image object `rim`. Then you can do as follows

```
Box <- owin(c(-50,50) * rim$xstep, c(-50,50) * rim$ystep)
BoxesUnion <- MinkowskiSum(pts, Box)
W <- intersect.owin(as.mask(rim), BoxesUnion)
```

This would give you the subset of the raster that is covered by the squares.
If you want to keep the squares separate, do something like

```
M <- as.mask(rim)
BoxList <- solapply(seq_len(npoints(pts)), 
                      function(i) intersect.owin(M, shift(Box, pts[i])))
```

Then `BoxList` is a list of the individual sub-rasters.

Comment: If I understand your proposition, `BoxList` is a List of windows ! It sounds great ! Now I don't understand how to use those windows to mask the initial raster or the `im`... I'm not comfortable with `owin` object.